# Getting only the values in Array not keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, stylesheet

What I'm trying to accomplish is using an array to link to CSS stylesheets.

First I create the function to be executed which is styles()
The styles() function looks like this..

```
//CSS Stylesheets Includes
function styles()
{
    $linkStyles = array(
    0 => 'main',
    1 => 'topBar',
    2 => 'globals',
    3 => 'search',
    4 => 'menu',
    5 => 'footer',
    6 => 'banner',
    7 => 'slideshow',
    8 => 'graphs',
    9 => 'contact',
    10 => 'news',
    11 => 'products',
    12 => 'support'
    );

    for($i = 0; $i <= count($linkStyles); $i++)
    {
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" charset="text/css" href="css/style_<?php array($linkStyles[$i]); ?>.css" /><?php
    }
}
```

Now what I'm having trouble with is working with the Array within the for() loop. I'm not understanding how to acquire just the value within the key of the array.

For example, If I look up the $linkStyles array under key 0 I want it to return just 'main' without the quotations of course.
The final output would be something like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" charset="text/css" href="css/style_main.css" />
```

of course since there's a loop, it would have 12 of the links to stylesheets, not just 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i get only values from var dump array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981320/how-do-i-get-only-values-from-var-dump-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($linkStyles as $v)
{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" charset="text/css" href="css/style_' . $v . '.css" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$linkStyles[$i]` while accessing an element of an array.

And take a look to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
array($linkStyles[$i]);
```

for this one:

```
echo $linkStyles[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for($i = 0; $i <= count($linkStyles); $i++)
{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' charset='text/css' href='css/style_$linkStyles[$i].css'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function styles()
{
    $linkStyles = array(
    0 => 'main',
    1 => 'topBar',
    2 => 'globals',
    3 => 'search',
    4 => 'menu',
    5 => 'footer',
    6 => 'banner',
    7 => 'slideshow',
    8 => 'graphs',
    9 => 'contact',
    10 => 'news',
    11 => 'products',
    12 => 'support'
    );

    foreach($linkStyles as $style)
    {
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" charset="text/css" href="css/style_<?php echo($style); ?>.css" /><?php
    }
}
```

Also, you dont need to assign numeric keys to the array elements if the number are going to be in sequence like that.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can use the php function "array_values"

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php