# how do i get only values from var dump array?

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

Is it possible to escape `array(1) { [0]=> string(12)}` from `var_dump($variable)` because I want to show only values from var_dump and except `array string`?

**Testing Code**

```
 <?php
 $array = array(
 "foo" => "bar",
 "bar" => "foo",
 100   => -100,
-100  => 100,
 );
 var_dump($array);
 ?>
```

**now results will be like this**

```
array(4) {
["foo"]=>
string(3) "bar"
["bar"]=>
string(3) "foo"
[100]=>
int(-100)
[-100]=>
int(100)
}
```

But I want to get only `bar` and `foo` values except string(3) and array(4)?

Comment: Only values without keys `echo implode(',', $array);`

Comment: No, because `var_dump()` is purely intended as a debugging function.... if you want to display only values you `echo`

Comment: You should add some context. What are you trying to do? Why do you need that?

Comment: `$array['foo']; $array['bar']`?

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r i have done what i want to do with `implode($array);` thanks friends

Comment: @edgematrix: Ah, fine. If you need the variable information (type, string-length etc.): [`call_user_func_array('var_dump', $array);`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15981451/2261774)

Answer (score 2):

Right here:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'=>'.$value."\n";
}
```

For each key-value pair, this will echo the items as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    100   => -100,
    -100  => 100
);

print_r($array);

$newArray = array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return (gettype($v) != 'string');
});

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [bar] => foo
    [100] => -100
    [-100] => 100
)
Array
(
    [100] => -100
    [-100] => 100
)
```

`$newArray` contains all values except strings. (you can change `!=` to `==` to get only the string values)

After your edit I think you may want this (accessing individual items in an associative array):

```
echo $array['bar'];
echo $array['foo'];
```

Outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
$array = array(
    "a" => "bar",
    "b" => "foo",
);


var_dump($array);
//bar
//foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
  $array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    100   => -100,
    -100  => 100,
  );

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
call_user_func_array('var_dump', $array);
```

That is using `var_dump()` on each value of the *`$array`* instead of the whole array:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    100   => -100,
    -100  => 100,
);

call_user_func_array('var_dump', $array);

echo implode(', ', $array); # for comparison
```

Output:

```
string(3) "bar"
string(3) "foo"
int(-100)
int(100)
bar, foo, -100, 100
```